# NSFetchedResultsController doesn't respond to changes in the number of sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm getting the following error when I delete a cell from the table view:

> Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections
> contained in the table view after the update (0) must be equal to the
> number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1),
> plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted,
> 0 deleted)

I'm using the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to respond to the changes in the number of section. I'm retrieving the data from a plist file in Core Data and each addition of the table view cell increases the number of sections accordingly, so 3 cells = 3 sections.

```swift
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let goal = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = goal.title
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let goal = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        self.context.delete(goal)
        self.saveContext()
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    let section = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)
    switch type {
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(section, with: .automatic)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

`context` is this:

```swift
var context : NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

How I load the saved Core Data onto FRC:

```
func loadSavedData() {
    if fetchedResultsController == nil {
        let request = Goal.createFetchRequest()
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        request.fetchBatchSize = 20
        
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.context, sectionNameKeyPath: "title", cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    }
    
    fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = goalPredicate
    
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print("Fetch failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks reasonable enough; I assume you’ve edited out the usual insert/update cases.  Can you expand on “3 cells = 3 sections”?  Is there only ever one cell per section?  Also, can you show how your FRC is setup?

Comment: When I print(fetchedResultsController.sections?.count) in the `numberOfSections` function, the number increases along with the increase in the number of cells. Is that not supposed to be happening for FRC? I added in my question how I load Core Data onto FRC.

Comment: Also I don't have the `insert` for `editingStyle` in the `commit` function because I'm not swiping or clicking on the cell to perform an insert edit, but only deletion. The insert is done in another screen to be saved into Core Data and loaded to the current page in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I changed the `sectionNameKeyPath` to `nil` in `NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)` and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try calling beginUpdates and endUpdates in these delegate apis also.

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
   tableView.endUpdates
}
    
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
   tableView.beginUpdates
}
```

if you still face issues then in this delegate function, try to call like this:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.performBatchUpdates {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.deleteSections(section, with: .automatic)
    } completion: { (status) in
        
    }
}
```